# Kubernetes ingress-nginx not returning http response header

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

im encountering an issue whereby ingress-nginx(reverse proxy) is not returning http response header (ETag) from application container.

It works fine without ingress.

[Missing http response header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GDHI.png)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

The following is a snippet of Ingress yaml file

```html
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ng-api-ngress
  namespace: ng-prod
  labels:
    app: numbergenerator
  annotations:
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers: etag
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-expose-headers: etag
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: kubernetes.docker.internal.api
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: ng-backend
            port:
              number: 80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this `Nginx ingress` annotation :

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      etag on;
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      more_set_headers "server: hide";
```

if Gzip is enabled Nginx ingress won't add or pass etag.

As much as i know etag wont generated by Nginx in reverse proxy configuration however if require you can generate and manage from backend code.

Comment: Hi Harsh Manvar, i include use-gzip: "false" in ingress controller configmap and confirmed it's working fine now

Comment: Hi @user3187494 How did you disable gzip in ingress yml. Can you please share the snippet